# Компилятор ругается и выдает такую ошибку: error "assignment to expression with array type". Подскажите в чём может быть проблема

Tags: c, массивы, файлы, c++11, структуры

```
char *tmp[50];
for(int i = 0; i < b-1; i++){
  for(int j = i+1; j < b; j++){
    if(strcmp(str[i].name, str[j].name)> 0){// сравнивается два элемента из массива структур 
      tmp[i] = str[i].name;
      str[i].name = str[j].name;
      str[j].name = tmp[i];
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: скорее всего вместо `tmp[i]` надо написать `tmp` либо переписать это на плюсах

Comment: Нужно определение поля `name` из типа `str[i]`. Подозреваю что `char name[50];`, но не уверен.